# Debug log wrapper

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11, logging, wrapper

I will be adding functionality and most likely additional refactoring, however a stringent review would be welcome before I build it further. I know documentation is probably a bit sparse but, you know how it is.  If you feel anything significantly warrants documentation, let me know. I know I understand the code; I don't know about others.

Please review code correctness, best practices, design and code formatting.

```
//File      debug.h
//Release   1.2.0.0
//Copyright Michael Mercer

/* Include code
#ifdef NDEBUG
    #include <debug.h>
#else
    #undef OBJECT_NAME
    #define OBJECT_NAME debugDefault    //Name object by file or project
    #include <debug.h>
    using namespace debug_1_2_0;        //Required to debug main() and NDEBUG ForwardCall
    debug OBJECT_NAME;                  //debug OBJECT_NAME(std::initializer_list<std::ostream*>); to set ostreams
#endif

DEBUG_MAIN  //Wrap main with debug diagnostics
{
    //DEBUG(Args...);
    //DEBUG_FUNC("Function name", function, function args...);
    //DEBUG_FUNC(function, function args...);
    return 0;
}
*/

#ifdef NDEBUG

    #undef DEBUG
    #undef DEBUG_FUNC
    #undef DEBUG_MAIN
    #define DEBUG(...)
    #define DEBUG_FUNC  ForwardCall
    #define DEBUG_MAIN  int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)

#else

    #undef DEBUG
    #undef DEBUG_FUNC
    #undef DEBUG_MAIN
    #define DEBUG       OBJECT_NAME.debugOutput
    #define DEBUG_FUNC  DEBUG

    #define DEBUG_MAIN                                  \
    int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)        \
    {                                                   \
        OBJECT_NAME.debugDiagnostics(argc, argv, envp); \
    }                                                   \
    int debug::main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)

#endif

#ifndef DEBUG_H //Include guard
#define DEBUG_H

#include <exception>    //for std::exception
#include <iostream>     //for std::ostream
#include <stdexcept>    //for std::logic_error
#include <windows.h>    //for GetStdHandle etc
#include <forward_list> //for std::forward_list
namespace debug_1_2_0
{   

    //Forward calls when NDEBUG
    template<typename... T, typename... Args>
    void ForwardCall(void funcToTry(T... Tp), Args&&... parameters)
    {
        (funcToTry)(static_cast<Args&&>(parameters)...);
    }

    //Forward calls when NDEBUG
    template<typename F, typename... T, typename... Args>
    auto ForwardCall(F funcToTry(T... Tp), Args&&... parameters) -> F
    {
        return (funcToTry)(static_cast<Args&&>(parameters)...);
    }

    //Forward calls when NDEBUG 
    template<typename... T, typename... Args>
    void ForwardCall(const char* const functionName,void funcToTry(T... Tp), Args&&... parameters)
    {
        (funcToTry)(static_cast<Args&&>(parameters)...);
    }

    //Forward calls when NDEBUG     
    template<typename F, typename... T, typename... Args>
    auto ForwardCall(const char* const functionName,F funcToTry(T... Tp), Args&&... parameters) -> F
    {
        return (funcToTry)(static_cast<Args&&>(parameters)...);
    }

#ifndef NDEBUG

    enum struct debugState {ENTER, EXIT, PROCESS};

    //Retreive file size
    __int64 FileSize(std::string name);

    class oStreams
    {
    private:
        std::forward_list<std::ostream*> listStreams;

    public:
        oStreams(std::initializer_list<std::ostream*> initOutStreams);

        typedef std::ostream& (manip)(std::ostream&);
        void operator<<(manip& m);

        template <typename T>
        void operator<<(T&& obj)
        {
            for (auto& x: listStreams)
                (*x) << static_cast<T&&>(obj);
        }
    };

    class debug
    {
    private:
        int debugIndentCount=0;
        const char* const enterRoutine = "Enter ";
        const char* const exitRoutine =  "Exit  ";
        oStreams debugStreams;

        //Output last remaining element of args...
        template <typename T>
        void logText(T&& firstOut)
        {
            debugStreams << static_cast<T&&>(firstOut);
        }

        //Output first element of args..., call recursively
        template <typename T, typename... Args>
        void logText(T&& firstOut, Args&&... remainder)
        {
            debugStreams << static_cast<T&&>(firstOut);
            logText(static_cast<Args&&>(remainder)...);
        }

        //Format and output args... to ostream
        template <typename... Args>
        void indentX(Args&&... debugText)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
            debugStreams << "# ";
            for(int x = 0; x < debugIndentCount; ++x)
                debugStreams << "   ";
            logText(static_cast<Args&&>(debugText)...);
            debugStreams << std::endl;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED|FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_BLUE);
        }

        //Output custom state and args...
        template <typename... Args>
        void debugOutput(debugState state, Args&&... debugText)
        {
            switch(state)
            {
            case debugState::ENTER:
                indentX(enterRoutine, static_cast<Args&&>(debugText)...);
                debugIndentCount++;
                break;
            case debugState::EXIT:
                if (debugIndentCount>0)
                    debugIndentCount--;
                indentX(exitRoutine, static_cast<Args&&>(debugText)...);
                break;
            case debugState::PROCESS:
                indentX(static_cast<Args&&>(debugText)...);
                break;
            default:
                throw std::logic_error("Debugging error: Incorrect enum debugState");
            }
        }

    public:

        debug(std::initializer_list<std::ostream*> oStreams = {&std::clog})
            : debugStreams(oStreams)
            {};

        ~debug(){};

        //Output args...
        template <typename... Args>
        void debugOutput(Args&&... debugText)
        {
            debugOutput(debugState::PROCESS,static_cast<Args&&>(debugText)...);
        }

        //Call funcToTry with args..., catch exception      
        template<typename... T, typename... Args>
        void debugOutput(void funcToTry(T... Tp), Args&&... parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                (funcToTry)(static_cast<Args&&>(parameters)...);
            }
            catch(std::exception& e)
            {
                debugOutput("EXCEPTION THROWN! ", e.what());
                throw;
            }
        }

        //Call funcToTry with args... and return F, catch exception
        template<typename F, typename... T, typename... Args>
        auto debugOutput(F funcToTry(T... Tp), Args&&... parameters) -> F
        {
            try
            {
                return (funcToTry)(static_cast<Args&&>(parameters)...);
            }
            catch(std::exception& e)
            {
                debugOutput("EXCEPTION THROWN! ", e.what());
                throw;
            }
        }

        //Output function name
        //Call void funcToTry with args..., catch exception     
        template<typename... T, typename... Args>
        void debugOutput(const char* const functionName,void funcToTry(T... Tp), Args&&... parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                debugOutput(debugState::ENTER,functionName);
                (funcToTry)(static_cast<Args&&>(parameters)...);
                debugOutput(debugState::EXIT,functionName);
            }
            catch(std::exception& e)
            {
                debugOutput("EXCEPTION THROWN! ", e.what());
                throw;
            }
        }

        //Output function name
        //Call funcToTry with args... and return F, catch exception         
        template<typename F, typename... T, typename... Args>
        auto debugOutput(const char* const functionName,F funcToTry(T... Tp), Args&&... parameters) -> F
        {
            try
            {
                debugOutput(debugState::ENTER,functionName);
                F returnValue = (funcToTry)(static_cast<Args&&>(parameters)...);
                debugOutput(debugState::EXIT,functionName," with ", returnValue);
                return returnValue;
            }
            catch(std::exception& e)
            {
                debugOutput("EXCEPTION THROWN! ", e.what());
                throw;
            }
        }

        int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp);

        void debugDiagnostics(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)
        {
            SYSTEMTIME stStart, stEnd;
            FILETIME ftStart,ftEnd;

            debugOutput(debugState::ENTER,"Debug Diagnostics");
            double fileSize = FileSize(argv[0]);
            debugOutput("file size in bytes = ",fileSize);
            debugOutput("file size in kilobytes = ",fileSize/1024);
            debugOutput(debugState::EXIT,"Debug Diagnostics");

            GetSystemTime(&stStart);
            debugOutput(debugState::ENTER,"Main");
            this->main(argc, argv, envp);
            debugOutput(debugState::EXIT,"Main");
            GetSystemTime(&stEnd);

            SystemTimeToFileTime (&stStart,&ftStart);
            SystemTimeToFileTime (&stEnd,&ftEnd);

            unsigned __int64 timeStart=ftStart.dwLowDateTime;
            unsigned __int64 timeEnd=ftEnd.dwLowDateTime;

            debugOutput(debugState::ENTER,"Debug Diagnostics");
            debugOutput("execution time is ", (timeEnd-timeStart)/10000000, " seconds");
            debugOutput("execution time is ", (timeEnd-timeStart)/10000, " milliseconds");
            debugOutput(debugState::EXIT,"Debug Diagnostics");
        }

    };  //class

#endif  //#ifndef NDEBUG

}       //namespace

#endif //DEBUG_H
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't quite get the whole picture of your code without a usage example, but there are a few aspects I can comment on. In order of appearance:

- `main()` with the extra `envp` parameter is not standard, though that format is accepted by the main compilers out there. Your code has a few Windows-specific portions, so I don't think portability is your concern anyway. You can read more about the signature of `main` in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main).
- `namespace debug_1_2_0`: It doesn't strike me as a good idea encoding the version number of a library in the names of things. When the version changes, what will you do?
- What you are trying to achieve with the several instances of `static_cast<T &&>()` through the code is what [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) does. You should use the latter since it is a clearer and standard way of doing it.
- Consider replacing the Visual Studio specific `__int64` with the standard `std::int64_t`, found in the [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) header. There is no advantage in using a compiler extension when a standard version of the same feature is also available.
- These two constants:

  > ```
  > const char* const enterRoutine = "Enter ";
  > const char* const exitRoutine =  "Exit  ";
  > ```

  Could be `static`, to ensure no data is duplicated if more than one class instance is created.
- Empty destructor in `~debug(){};` is really not necessary.
- Minor point, but you are using a somewhat unusual naming convention for your class types. `camelCase` methods are usually combined with `PascalCase` class names, so I would expect your classes to be `Debug` and `OStreams`.